# Why do we get these "invalid" intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

We have an app with an Activity that can be started in two ways:

- From another Activity - always with some extra data filled in
- From deep linking

As far as I can see this is always working just fine. We either get the `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with a data URI, or we get some string extras.

However, we have a very few instances where action is `Intent.ACTION_MAIN` and there are no extra data.

The `toString()` of the Intent is as follows (class name changed):

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10400000 cmp=com.example.OurActivity }
```

[`Intent.getExtras()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) returns null, [`Intent.getDataString()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getDataString()) returns null.

**In which cases can this happen? Why is the category for the Activity [`Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)? How can we get the data needed to show the user the right contents?**

`launchMode` is not specified for the Activity. The only `IntentFilter` in `AndroidManifest.xml` is for the deep linking (and not the launcher category).

The issue happens on Android 4-6 on a wide range of devices.

**Edit: Forgot to mention the flags:**

As the print out suggests the flags for the Intent are [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT). I suppose that could be relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, I nailed it:

There're launchers, like [**Nova Launcher**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) which allows users to start with **any** of app's `Activities`, instead of the normal flow:

[image]

**For example**, you can add a shortcut on your desktop to start Gmail client with Account setup Activity.

And in this case, Activity is being started with empty `Extras` and technically it becomes a launcher's `Activity`.

Comment: I belive you are right. Nova Launcher didn't send any action or category, but other launchers may do it a little bit different/right.

Answer (score 0):

Now that AndroidManifest.xml is manipulated by the build system, it often happens that libraries that you include also add things to the manifest, which I suspect may be happening here.

Although you state that there is only one IntentFilter in the manifest, have you actually checked the installed app to see what its manifest says (rather than relying on what you think you put in your source code)?

Various apps are available in the Play Store to show you the manifest of an installed app - including App Detective (which I wrote).

Comment: Good suggestion! However, nothing was injected for that activity. (Nice app though! Maybe something to change ManifestViewer with in my dev app (https://github.com/roys/java-android-developertools#developer-tools-for-android ).)